# SAM Conversion with Generics

Tags: generics, kotlin, interface

I have my interfaced defined like so:

```
interface OnItemClickDelegate<T: Entity> {
    fun onItemClick(entity: T?)
}
```

Right now I have my interfaced defined anonymously in a different class:

```
var itemClickDelegate = object : OnItemClickDelegate<Derived> {
        override fun onItemClick(entity: Derived?) {
            doSomethingWith(entity)
        }
    }
```

This compiles fine, but when I switch it to:

```
var itemClickDelegate = OnItemClickDelegate<Derived> { entity -> doSomethingWith(entity) }
```

I get a compiler error saying:

```
Interface OnItemClickDelegate does not have constructors
```

How do I write my declaration in short notation?

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-7770

Answer (score 4):

Sadly, Kotlin does not support this syntax out of the box for kotlin interfaces, only java one (whether you use generics or not).

What you can do though is this :

```
interface OnItemClickDelegate<T : Entity> {
    fun onItemClick(entity: T?)

    companion object {
        inline operator fun <T : Entity> invoke(crossinline op: (entity: T?) -> Unit) =
            object : OnItemClickDelegate<T> {
                override fun onItemClick(entity: T?) = op(entity)
            }
    }
}
```

This way you can instantiate a listener like this :

```
  val delegate = OnItemClickDelegate<Entity> {
                    //todo -> insert your callback code here
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

From Kotlin 1.4 onwards, just add `fun` before the interface declaration and you're good to go, like so:

```
fun interface OnItemClickDelegate<T : Entity> {
    fun onItemClick(entity: T?)
}
```

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew14.html#sam-conversions-for-kotlin-interfaces